# How to extract everything between two keywords in perl

Tags: text-extraction

Need to extract everything between start and end.

the below code works if there is no \n.

```
$mystring = "The start text always precedes \n the end of the text.";
if($mystring =~ m/start(.*?)end/) {
    print $1;
}
```

o/p should be - text always precedes \n the

Answer (score 0):

Study [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), in particular the `/s` modifier.